# How to prevent timing attack

Tags: php

I’m trying to secure my web application with users’ accounts against timing attack. In particular, I can imagine the use of a timing attack to determine my existing user's email addresses at the registration form. When a new user wants to register, I check my database for the email address he submitted. If the email address exists in my database already, I send him an email saying that he has registered before and that he should use the Forgotten Password feature. If the email address does not exist in my database, I do much more staff on the server side – such as creating a random token to be send to his email address as part of a link to follow to create a password, of course inserting to the database this token along with the submitted email address and username. And a few more things (i.e. checking the username for the odd case that two different users are registering at the same time and desire to have the same username). The first scenario takes much less time to compute – I merged it on a WAMP server, and the first scenario never takes longer than 4 milliseconds while the second scenario always takes at least 13 milliseconds.

I have come with the solution below. Is my solution sufficient enough? And even if it is, are there any better solutions?

```
<?php
  $time = time();
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  //execute query to find out if the email exists. Store the result in $exists
  if(!$exists){
        //perform all the necessary steps mentioned above
        //send the email with the link
  }else{
        //send the email warning that account exists
  }

  while(time()-$time < 3){
  }
  header("Location: /index.php?email=success", true, 301);
?>
```

Comment: I don't know much about this topic, but on an actual internet connection, wouldn't the latency be too varied to notice this? This isn't an issue I've ever considered so I'm interested

Comment: Well, I do not know - have to try. But in theory, it should. For timing attacks are enough differences in microseconds if they are consistent.

Comment: I am fascinated to know what your web site is that it requires this level of security. Must be a high value target... But yes anything that messes with the output times, why not do some randomness so every time it is different. I would also suggest you don't discuss your solution in a public forum,.

Comment: It really bugs me that someone would intentionally halter the speed of their application but how would the attacker time this if there's no feedback from the server? How are you timing it?

Comment: What you can do is to use a random number on the while loop, instead of "3".

Comment: @matt : I timed it right before the line with `header`  - instead of the halting while loop. The attacker can merge the time from his submit until the response header is transmitted to his browser. I think, that with a fast and stable connection he would notice differences. I might be wrong and just worrying about the non-existent problem, that's why I ask the question.

Comment: To me, randomness seems to be unnecessary: timing attack will be impossible if the attacker gets every time different results as well as if he gets every time the same result.

Comment: Unless you are securing launch codes for ICBMs this is probably overkill for just about any application/site.

Comment: Randomness is necessary, if your server experiences lag or the corresponding service is down (perhaps your mail server gets DDOS'd) then the process will continue to execute over the 'same result'. This is why attackers love to DDOS services prior to exploiting servers. You never know **how long** the service will take to respond so perhaps set a cut off time? If you're that concerned about security then this question is probably too broad and would take an article to answer.